# Session automatically unset into HAProxy Server

Tags: haproxy

Its very critical issue. I set session using following code .

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['price'] = 100;
```

After one minute, session automatically destroy or unset. Its happen single time in each day. I am using HAProxy strategy. I think its server issue.Please help me ASAP.

Comment: Do you mean it happens exactly one time each day?  Is it always at the same time?

Comment: Where do you observe the loss of session data? From the client side? How does it manifest itself? Are you asking for session stickiness or...?